# How can I fill in gaps in a data frame by group in R?

Tags: r, grouping, sequence, series, fill

I have a data frame with a time series, a set of events, and an ID. I've joined two data frames by a shared time column, but I'd like to fill in the gaps in events.

Here is a simplified example, with the value column that I used to join the data frames, then the event and ID columns. I want to somehow fill in the columns for events and ID between the first (start) and last (end) event entry.

```
a<-c(seq(from = 150, to = 213, by = 3))
b<-c("start","","","mid","","end","", "",
         "start", "", "", "end", "", "", "",
         "start", "", "end", "start", "mid", "", "end")
c<-c("A","","","A","","A","", "",
         "A", "", "", "A", "", "", "",
         "B", "", "B", "B", "B", "", "B")

(data<-data.frame(value = a, event = b, ID = c))
```

Here is the goal, with the events and ID filled in between start and end:

```
agoal<-c(seq(from = 150, to = 213, by = 3))
bgoal<-c("start","start","start","mid","mid","end","", "",
         "start", "start", "start", "end", "", "", "",
         "start", "start", "end", "start", "mid", "mid", "end")
cgoal<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","", "",
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "", "", "",
         "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")

(goal<-data.frame(value = agoal, event = bgoal, ID = cgoal))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option with [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

1. Convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` - `setDT`
2. Loop over the columns specified in `.SDcols` - 'event', 'ID'
3. Replace the blank (`""`) with `NA` - `na_if`
4. Use `na.locf0` (from `zoo`) to fill the NA elements with previous non-NA and assign (`:=`) back to the columns
5. Get the row index (`.I`) where the 'event' value is `duplicated` and where 'event' is "end" grouped by the run-length-id (`rleid`) of event
6. Extract the row index (`$V1`) and assign those 'event', 'ID' to blank

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
setDT(data)[, c("event", "ID") := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
        na.locf0(na_if(x, ""))), .SDcols = event:ID]
data[data[, .I[duplicated(event) & event == "end"] , 
         rleid(event)]$V1, c("event", "ID") := .("", "")]
```

-output

```
data
    value event ID
 1:   150 start  A
 2:   153 start  A
 3:   156 start  A
 4:   159   mid  A
 5:   162   mid  A
 6:   165   end  A
 7:   168         
 8:   171         
 9:   174 start  A
10:   177 start  A
11:   180 start  A
12:   183   end  A
13:   186         
14:   189         
15:   192         
16:   195 start  B
17:   198 start  B
18:   201   end  B
19:   204 start  B
20:   207   mid  B
21:   210   mid  B
22:   213   end  B
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr` for this task:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(case_when(event == "end" ~ -1,
                         event == "start" ~ 1,
                         TRUE ~ 0)),
         across(c(-value, -grp), ~ ifelse(.x == "" & grp == 1, NA_character_, .x))) %>% 
  fill(c(-value), .direction="down") %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

returns

```r
   value event ID
1    150 start  A
2    153 start  A
3    156 start  A
4    159   mid  A
5    162   mid  A
6    165   end  A
7    168         
8    171         
9    174 start  A
10   177 start  A
11   180 start  A
12   183   end  A
13   186         
14   189         
15   192         
16   195 start  B
17   198 start  B
18   201   end  B
19   204 start  B
20   207   mid  B
21   210   mid  B
22   213   end  B
```

Comment: I like this idea! It didn't seem to work for me though. I see that the grp column is made and it scores "1" for the correct rows, but the fill command doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Strange... Are you using `tidyr::fill`?

Comment: I am, so it seems like mystery to me! I know that sometimes the order of package loading matters, so I tried specifically designating which package the functions used and still no luck...